# Infinity is returned when calculating average in array

Tags: ruby, average, reduce, infinity

Why does the following method return infinity when trying to find the average volume of a stock:

```
class Statistics

    def self.averageVolume(stocks)
        values = Array.new
        stocks.each do |stock|
            values.push(stock.volume)
        end
        values.reduce(:+).to_f / values.size
    end

end

class Stock
    attr_reader :date, :open, :high, :low, :close, :adjusted_close, :volume
    def initialize(date, open, high, low, close, adjusted_close, volume)
        @date = date
        @open = open
        @high = high
        @low = low
        @close = close
        @adjusted_close = adjusted_close
        @volume = volume
    end

    def close
        @close
    end

    def volume
        @volume
    end
end

CSV.foreach(fileName) do |stock|
    entry = Stock.new(stock[0], stock[1], stock[2], stock[3], stock[4], stock[5], stock[6])
    stocks.push(entry)
end
```

Here is how the method is called:

```
Statistics.averageVolume(stocks)
```

Output to console using a file that has 251 rows:

```
stock.rb:32: warning: Float 23624900242507002003... out of range
Infinity
```

Warning is called on the following line: `values.reduce(:+).to_f / values.size`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and let us know exactly what line the warning is happening on.

Comment: warning happens on the following line ```values.reduce(:+).to_f / values.size```.

Comment: Stick a breakpoint after the `end` on line 7 and see what `values` looks like.

Comment: Dividing by zero is a good way to break things pretty quickly. If that's an empty array...

Comment: Pro tip: If you have an array that maps 1:1 to the arguments of a function, splat it out. `Stock.new(*stock)` is way less messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing average functions you'll want to pay close attention to the possibility of division by zero.

Here's a fixed and more Ruby-like implementation:

```
def self.average_volume(stocks)
  # No data in means no data out, can't calculate.
  return if (stocks.empty?)

  # Pick out the `volume` value from each stock, then combine
  # those with + using 0.0 as a default. This forces all of
  # the subsequent values to be floating-point.
  stocks.map(&:volume).reduce(0.0, &:+) / values.size
end
```

In Ruby it's strongly recommended to keep variable and method names in the `x_y` form, like `average_volume` here. Capitals have significant meaning and indicate constants like class, module and constant names.

You can test this method using a mock Stock:

```
require 'ostruct'

stocks = 10.times.map do |n|
  OpenStruct.new(volume: n)
end

average_volume(stocks)
# => 4.5
average_volume([ ])
# => nil
```

If you're still getting infinity it's probably because you have a broken value somewhere in there for `volume` which is messing things up. You can try and filter those out:

```
stocks.map(&:value).reject(&:nan?)...
```

Where testing vs. `nan?` might be what you need to strip out junk data.

Comment: Thank you for providing a clear example. I could manage to find the error; whenever creating a new stock, the volume would be stored as a string. Using [to_f](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/to_f) on the string therefore converting it to a float fixed this issue.